# Polymorphic Association Pydantic

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I'm refactoring a code and I'm facing a trouble that could be solved using polymorphic association but I don't know how to apply this to Pydantic.

I have a Client model and a Business model. Both can have more than one phone - previously we used to store the phones as an array of strings but reading about database normalization I realized that I could work with a separate table only to store phones. My current models look like this for Client:

```py
class ClientModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = "reduto_clients"

    client_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True)
    brain_id = Column(String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
    business_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey("reduto_business.business_id"))
    document = Column(String(15), nullable=False, unique=True)
    name = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    email = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    address_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey("reduto_addresses.address_id"))
    score_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey("reduto_scores.score_id"))
    created_at = Column(DateTime)

    business_associate = relationship("BusinessModel", back_populates="client_associate")
```

For business:

```py
class BusinessModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = "reduto_business"

    business_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True)
    brain_id = Column(String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
    document = Column(String(15), nullable=False, unique=True)
    official_name = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    trade_name = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    email = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    address_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey("reduto_addresses.address_id"))
    tax_regime = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    tax_regime_status = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    tax_regime_status_date = Column(DateTime)
    activity_fk = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey("reduto_business_activity.activity_id"))
    created_at = Column(DateTime)

    client_associate = relationship("ClientModel", back_populates="business_associate")
```

For Phones:

```py
class PhoneModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = "reduto_phones"

    phone_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True)
    owner_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey("reduto_business.business_id"))
    phone = Column(String(15), nullable=False, unique=True)
    
    owner = relationship() # i don't know how to handle this
```

How can I implement polymorphic association so a phone can reference either a Client or a Business?

Comment: So firstly, you talk about Pydantic, but your code looks a lot more like SQLAlchemy, so I'll assume that's what you're talking about. In that case this is more of a database modelling question than Python. I'd suggest googling "SQL polymorphic association", there are several common solitions for this problem. Also, note that dstabase normalization is not the end all be all, it depends on how you're using your data. In many cases, using e.g. PostgreSQL's `array` data type might be a preferrable solution.